# System.Web.UI.Timer inteference with event handling?

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

I'm currently having a problem with what seems like the Timer_Tick event interfering with the event handling for other controls within the UpdatePanel.

For now I have a Countdown label and some buttons inside an UpdatePanel. The Timer is outside the UpdatePanel and its Tick event is registered as a trigger for the panel. On every Tick, the Countdown's Text property is modified.

Whenever a button is clicked, a pop-up box will appear. However, I notice that if I click the button just when a Tick occurs, nothing happens. I'm assuming that it is because the Click event does not register while the UpdatePanel is in the process of rendering its updated contents.

Should I be using another type of timer instead? Is there a way to force the Click event to interrupt the Tick event? Or are there other ways to fix this issue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can nest your UpdatePanels so that your Label has it's own UpdatePanel.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, rick. I've tried doing that before but it didn't seem to work for me back then. However, it seems that it was because I left both UpdatePanels' update modes as **Always** instead of **Conditional**. I'm not too sure how the update modes actually cause the problem, but changing them to **Conditional** seems to be the fix.